# Use JavaScript code formatting for questions tagged with TypeScript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, syntax-highlighting

See title - questions tagged with [typescript](/questions/tagged/typescript) (a superset of JavaScript) should have code samples colorized according to the JavaScript code coloring rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds reasonable. Done.